# Post semaphore in shared memory crashes

Tags: c++, shared-memory

I have 2 processes:

- producer: creates an `Transaction` object inside a shared memory then waiting for consumer to read the data. The waiting is done via a semaphore which is a member of `Transaction`
- consumer: reads the `Transaction` object created by producer and tells producer the reading is done by posting semaphore in `Transaction` object.

Consumer is able to read the data from shared memory but it crashes when it tries to post semaphore.
What's wrong with this implementation?

```
//producer
#include <string>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
#include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

constexpr char g_shared_mem_name[]="/our_shared_mem_new";

class Transaction
{
public:
    virtual ~Transaction() = default;
    Transaction(const uint32_t f_count) : m_count{f_count}{}
    
    sem_t m_sem;

    uint32_t m_count{0};
};

void* createSharedMem(const char *f_name, const size_t f_size) {
    int fd = shm_open(f_name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd != -1) {
        // A new shared memory object initially has zero length.
        // The size of the object can be set using ftruncate.  
        // The newly allocated bytes of a shared memory object are
        // automatically initialized to 0
        if (ftruncate(fd, f_size) == -1) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        return mmap(NULL, f_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 );
    }
    else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

int main()
{   
    void * shared_mem = createSharedMem(g_shared_mem_name, sizeof(Transaction));
    if ( shared_mem ) 
    {
        Transaction* shared_obj = new(shared_mem) Transaction(2022);
        
        if( sem_init(&shared_obj->m_sem,1,0) == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Unable to initialize m_sem_init\n";
        }

        //waiting for consumer to finish reading data
        if( sem_wait(&shared_obj->m_sem) == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Error on waiting for semaphore\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Unable to create shared object\n";
    }

    shm_unlink(g_shared_mem_name);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Consumer

```
#include <string>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
#include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

constexpr char g_shared_mem_name[]="/our_shared_mem_new";

class Transaction
{
public:
    virtual ~Transaction() = default;
    Transaction(const uint32_t f_count) : m_count{f_count}{}
    
    sem_t m_sem;

    uint32_t m_count{0};
};

void* openSharedMem(const char * f_name, const size_t f_size) {
    int fd = shm_open(f_name, O_RDONLY, 0);
    if( fd != -1 ) {
        return mmap(NULL, f_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 );
    }
    else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

int main()
{   
    void* shared_mem = openSharedMem(g_shared_mem_name, sizeof(Transaction));
    if (shared_mem) {
        Transaction * m_inst = (Transaction*)shared_mem;
        std::cout << "value of cnt:" << m_inst->m_count << std::endl;
        
        //crash here
        if (sem_post(&m_inst->m_sem) == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Unable to post semaphore\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open shared object\n";
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output

> value of cnt:2022
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: `sem_post` needs to write to the semaphore but you have mapped it read only.

Comment: @kaylum: yes, that's problem. I fixed the flags and it works, thanks